# How do I add a path in the home directory in GitHub Actions CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm following [this documentation article](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path) and at the moment I have this code:

```
echo '::add-path::$HOME/.local/bin'
```

However, this doesn't work. I tried both single and double quotes. My only guess is that it doesn't like `$HOME`, but I would really like to avoid hard-coding `/home/runner` to be home directory agnostic.

Is there a way to add a local path in GitHub Actions?

Comment: Can you post the complete workflow yaml definition? My guess is that you're trying to access the path in the same step, but it's only available in the following steps as per `Prepends a directory to the system PATH variable for all subsequent actions in the current job. The currently running action cannot access the new path variable.` (source: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path)

Comment: No, I'm accessing it in another step in the same job.

Answer (score 8):

It seems to work just fine

```yaml
- run: |
       mkdir -p $HOME/.local/bin
       cp $(which ls) $HOME/.local/bin/lets-see
       echo ::add-path::$HOME/.local/bin
- run: lets-see -a
```